# Socket.io with pm2cluster

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pm2

I have an existing application of node.js and socket.io with forever . But now I would like to use, pm2 cluster module instead of forever. But I have been facing some difficulties with socket.io and the cluster instances., as at few places the message is lost. So I read a little online to use another module called socket.io-with-pm2-cluster. Which acts as a plugin. But while using it., it asks me to configure in a way that each instance will have to listen to different ports. Like if the app is running on port 3000, the instance 0,1,23 will have to use 3001,3002,3003,3004. Can anyone suggest if it is the right approach ? Or any other work around s to make this possible ?

Comment: Have you tried setting mode to websocket?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `socket.io-redis`  for this purpose which is [recommended](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) approach by socket.io. So if you scale to multiple computers in future this will work fine as expected but in the current approach may be its failed to work on multiple computers like in case of AWS, in that case, you can also use a sticky session of LB but this.

socket.io needs to keep the socket open to get events from the server back to the client (and vice-versa) and you are running multiple workers so that is why you getting  "few places the message is lost".

**Sticky load balancing**

> If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different
>   processes or machines, you have to make sure that requests associated
>   with a particular session id connect to the process that originated
>   them.

you need to introduce layer that make your service stateless, you can use **[socket.io-redis](https://github.com/luoyjx/socket.io-redis-stateless)**

> By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run
>   multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that
>   can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

**Passing events between nodes**

you want to have multiple Socket.IO nodes accepting connections, if you want to broadcast events to everyone (or even everyone in a certain room) you’ll need some way of passing messages between processes or computers.

The interface in charge of routing messages is what we call the **Adapter**. You can implement your own on top of the socket.io-adapter (by inheriting from it) or you can use the one we provide on top of Redis: `socket.io-redis`:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Then the following call:

```
io.emit('hi', 'all sockets');
```

will be broadcast to every node through the Pub/Sub mechanism of Redis.

You can read further details [here](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/)